# Margin through loops

Tags: php, css

I have got this php code

```
 $count = 1;
    $margin='';
        while ($data=$query->fetch_row()) {
                $count == 2 ? $margin='style="margin-top:250;"' : $margin = '';
                        $count == 3 ? $count = 0 : $count++;
                           $firstname = $data[0];
                           $lastname=$data[1];
                           $username=$data[2];
                           ?>
                      <div id='Results' <?php echo $margin?>>
    <a href='$page'><img name='Searchimg' title='<?php echo ucfirst($username);?>' 
                      src='../img/".$img."' id='UserimgS'></a>
    <a id='Inf' href='$page'><?php echo ucfirst($username) ?></a>
<a id='Sinf' href='$page'> "<?php echo ucfirst($firstname)." ".ucfirst($lastname) ?>"</a></div>
            <?php
                }
```

And this css

```
#Results{
        position:absolute;
    }
```

But when i get 3 results it show margin only on second one not third

Comment: id should be unique use classes

Comment: Check a value of $count before while

Comment: But id is not changing anything @Akshay

Comment: It is not related to the question @RealSlimShady just saying id should be unique cause if you are using jquery or javascript you will have trouble

Comment: Oh okay thanks) @Akshay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change $count == 2 with $count >= 2. So the third block will also have the margin style.

Comment: Yes thanks it is working now!But now they both have margin of 250 can i add +250 for each next?

Comment: You can add a variable for your margin's value and add 250 each time.

Comment: I've tried this     $int=250;
$count >= 2 ? $margin='style="margin-top:".$int.";"' : $margin = '';
  $int++;
                 But it didn't work.Sorry i am pretty bad in PHP

Comment: $int = $int + 250 instead of $int++

Comment: Thanks!But in the beggining $int should be 0 not 250

Answer (score 0):

$count value must init with 0, as $count = 0

Comment: I tried VSnake's answer and it worked.When   $count = 0
Second one has not got margin

Comment: Do you want to show margin on every item but not first?

Comment: For example second div has margin 250 i want third to have 500 and fourth 750 and so on

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to set inline styles with php if it's not abdolutely necessary. If you don't want to use css nth-child / first-child / last-child selectors to support old browsers you could give the elements classes like first, last or result-1, result-2 etc. and set the appropriate styles with css.

Also, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same id on the same page.

I'd recommend using the css nth-child approach and using a polyfill if support for old browsers is needed.

Your code doesn't show what the initial value of $count is so its hard to say what the problem is.  The code would imho be easier to read if you refactored the ternaries to if statements for example like this:

```
$count = 0
while(...) {
    $count++;
    $class = "";
    if ($count > 2) {
        $class = "last";
        $count = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But in nth child i do not know how many elements will be there

Comment: That's why you can use last-child. One thing to remember with last-child css selector is that it selects the last element of the parent, so itnonly works when there is nothing after the listed elements in their immediate parent (e.g. pagination etc. must be placed outside the immediate parent)

Comment: But what about divs before last?

Comment: I didn't realise you were positioning the elements with the margins. It would be a __much__ better solution to not apply `position: absolute;` to the result elements and have them float below each other normally. I thought you just wanted a special style for the last element.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment,

> For example second div has margin 250 i want third to have 500 and fourth 750 and so on

Here's the solution:

```
$margin = 0;
while ($data=$query->fetch_row()) {
    $firstname = $data[0];
    $lastname=$data[1];
    $username=$data[2];
?>
    <div id='Results' style="margin-top:<?php echo $margin; ?>px;">
        <a href='$page'><img name='Searchimg' title='<?php echo ucfirst($username);?>' src='../img/".$img."' id='UserimgS'></a>
        <a id='Inf' href='$page'><?php echo ucfirst($username) ?></a>
        <a id='Sinf' href='$page'> "<?php echo ucfirst($firstname)." ".ucfirst($lastname) ?>"</a>
    </div>
<?php
    $margin += 250;
}
```